# Plot of a histogram is exported with wrong ticks if log-transformed data are used

Tags: export, histograms

I've generated a histogram of my data, using their log values, and exported the resulting plot as pdf. To my surprise, the ticks in exported plot were replaced by the logarithm of the ticks in the histogram in the notebook (please see MWE below).
This inconsistency seems to be a bug to me. I'm using MMA 11.2 on Windows 10.

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1000], {"Log", Automatic}]
Export["wrongTicks.pdf", %]
```

output:
[image]

pdf:
[image]

Comment: try an explicit *bspec* instead of automatic eg , `{"Log", 10}`

Comment: oh yes, I tried. It doesn't work also. (Or, more precisely, it works only the first time after I switched from, for instance  `{"Log", {{0.001, .01, .1, 1, 10, 100}}}`  or `{"Log", Automatic}` to `{"Log", 5}`. The second evaluation of the same code exposes the same bug.)

Comment: ok, I cant reproduce this in v10.1.   Can you see if other export formats have the same issue?

Comment: seems to work as expected with all raster formats and svg. Problems are only with eps and pdf files. With eps is stable reproducible, and with pdf -- behaves unpredictable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug appears to have been fixed sometime before the release of version 13.0:

[image]