# Exporting histogram to PDF with log scaled heights does not seem to work on 11.2

Tags: plotting, export, histograms, pdf-format, logarithmic-scale

I'm on version 11.2 and using Windows 10. Here is some data and a histogram of it with log scaled heights.

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1000];
histogram = Histogram[data, Automatic, {"Log", "Count"}]
```

[image]

Exporting it as PDF causes the ticks to revert back to linear scaling.

```
Export["histogram.pdf",histogram];
SystemOpen@%
```

[image]

Is there a way to export to PDF while keeping the logarithmic height scaling, other than upgrading to a later version? Notice that logarithmic bin width specification [used to suffer from the same problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/288012/37297) but has at some point been fixed, and at least in version 13.3 this one has been too.

Comment: works for me. V 13.3  on windows 10. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX8J9.png)  You should always indicate the version you are using and the OS.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [Plot of a histogram is exported with wrong ticks if log-transformed data are used](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/159199/9490)

Comment: @JasonB. See the last paragraph, it is not. The question is even linked.

Comment: It looks like the same bug to me, and it has been fixed in the most recent version of the software.

Comment: @JasonB. Logarithmic bin width specification was fixed earlier and exports correctly also in 11.2. Logarithmic height specification does not export correctly in 11.2. I was asking specifically if there is a workaround other than upgrading the version, and it is completely unclear to me why a workaround to the linked question would automatically work also here. Maybe I just don't get it, can you please explain?

Comment: @Kiro - I'm sorry, I don't really have access to version 11.2 to check so I could definitely be wrong.  I just read both questions as saying that a histogram created with log ticks display correctly in a notebook but incorrectly in the exported PDF, both posts explicitly state version 11.2, and both seem to work fine in the current version.  One workaround is to take a screenshot snippet of the plot in the notebook and export that image as a pdf or paste it into another program to create the PDF.  Not the greatest workaround, maybe better with notebook magnification set high.